# how to replace a specific char occurrences in string after a given substring

Tags: linux, bash, shell, replace

I have a string Contain key=value format separated by #
I am trying to replace the '=' char occurrences with ':' in the value of TITLE using BASH script.

```
"ID=21566#OS=Linux#TARGET_END=Synchronica#DEPENDENCY=Independent#AUTOMATION_OS=Linux#AUTOMATION_TOOL=JSystem#TITLE=Session tracking. "DL Started" Status Reported.Level=none"
```

later on i am parsing this string to execute the eval operation

```
eval $(echo $test_line | sed 's/"//g' | tr '#' '\n' | tr ' ' '_' | sed 's/=/="/g' | sed 's/$/"/g')
```

When the `sed 's/=/="/g'` section will also change `..Level=none` to 
`Level="none`
This leads to

```
eval: line 52: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

What will be right replace bash command to replace my string ?

Comment: Just remove the `/g` modifier from `sed 's/=/="/g'`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider pure-bash solution to bring the variables into bash, avoiding the (risky) eval.

```
IFS=# read -a kv <<<"ID=21566#OS=Linux#TARGET_END=Synchronica#..."

for kvp in "${kv[@]}" ; do
    declare "$kvp"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Why the eval is risky?

Comment: I'm assuming the input comes from external system. This open your script to shell injection. e.g. , if the input will contain `" ; rm -rf /` (quotes, followed by any command) - it will execute that command - in the `rm` -  it can wipe out part of your system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to solve it.
I will add sed 's/=/:/8g' to my eval command. 
It will replace 8th to nth occurrences of '='.
The action will only effect the value of TITLE as expected.

```
 eval $(echo $test_line | sed 's/=/:/8g' | sed 's/"/"/g' | tr '#' '\n' | tr ' ' '_' | sed 's/=/="/g' | sed 's/$/"/g')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this :

```sh
echo '"ID=21566#OS:Linux#TARGET_END:Synchronica#DEPENDENCY:Independent#AUTOMATION_OS:Linux#AUTOMATION_TOOL:JSystem#TITLE:Session tracking. "DL Started" Status Reported.Level=none"' \
 | 
sed -E 's/(#)?([A-Z_]+)(=)/\1\2:/g'
```

Let me know if it works for you.